# How to Map GUID in ADF

Tags: dataflow, azure-data-factory

As I am new to ADF, I would like to know abt the following Mapping.
I know that in SSIS there was a typecast to convert string to Guid by using (DT_GUID)..
I have explored in ADF, and noticed that there is no such conversation possible in ADF.

Is that so? In that case to handle this scenario?

How to achieve this in ADF??

Source(.csv) column(AccountGUID String) to Target(SQL Server) Column(AccountGUID uniqueIdentifier) in ADF.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Sree, do you want to convert column AccountGUID  with GUID to Sink table?

Comment: Hi @Sree, hope you're doing well. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the data conversion: create GUDI for source string column `AccountGUID` and mapping to sink table column `AccountGUID`, you must use the Data Flow.

Just for now, Data Factory Data flow doesn't support the function/expression `GUID()`. It means that we can't achieve that in Data Factory.